# Dungeons and Dragons cover

Tags: tikz-pgf, covers

I am making a small homebrew project for Dungeons and Dragons and I would like to make a cover to look similarly to original products. For example this one:

https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81objtUow1L.jpg

I started with the following:

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \incgraph[documentpaper,
        width=\paperwidth,
        height=\paperheight,
        overlay={
            \node[white] at (5, 10) {\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont Infernal Dungeons};
        }
    ]{img/cover.jpg} \end{titlepage}
```

This displays the cover in full page (woo-hoo) and draws some text, but it's unclear to me really how to get the rest done.

First, positioning of the text - I was trying to figure out how the coordinate system works for nodes. Every examples I see uses simple values (0,0) or (0,1), but if I use these most of my text disappears.

Second, how can I change the font for the title (and later subtitle) to one that matches the official projects (there are fonts available that mimic that)

And finally: how can I add additional images on top of the cover (most importantly the red diamomond).

Are these things possible through the tikz overlay I have currently?

Comment: See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/194703) for instructions how to draw on top of a pic and to put text there.

Comment: OTOH, I recall when the 'New Zork Times" had to change their name to "Gnu News" (or was it "Yak Facts") due to a copyright suit  See https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=2ahUKEwjUitC-9tvkAhUIEawKHb5QAtwQFjABegQIAxAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ifarchive.org%2Fif-archive%2Finfocom%2FNZT%2BTSL%2FNZT44.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1dh8HnJgL80qvFMFbGfFHW

Comment: @JohnKormylo Can you elaborate why they had to change their name?

Comment: @gruszczy - Besides the obvious?  Not really.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Nothing from your comment is obvious to me. I conclude from your cooment that you are implying I am going to encounter some copyright issues - but I am very unclear what exactly you are referring to.

Comment: @gruszczy - They were sued by the New York Times, even though their name was an obvious satire.  If the image was taken from copyrighted material, you "could" get sued.  It depends on how lawyer happy they are.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for explaining. I am not planning the use the image linked in the question - I merely want to have a similar design (similar font, diamond, title/subtitle). This is a common practice on DMs Guild (https://www.dmsguild.com/)

Comment: Wizards actually even share a lot of art for use in materials published on the page. I don't know if this specific image, but a lot of others are available to authors publishing their.